# nginx не проксирует запросы

Tags: nginx, proxy

Поднимаю проксю nginx. Сделал вот такой конфиг

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  myproxy.com www.myproxy.com;

    proxy_redirect           on;
    proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header         Host $http_host;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
        }
}
```

Затем, дёргаю с моей тачки курлом проксю с указанием целевого хоста:

```
curl -x 4.5.6.7:80 http://1.2.3.4:8080
```

Но в ответ получаю страничку nginx. В чём косяк может быть?

Comment: если хотите настроить nginx как forward proxy, то в proxy_pass надо подставлять [переданные аргументы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083709/4827341). фиксированное значение — это reverse proxy. p.s. ну и не уверен, что указание порта может оказать какое-то влияние.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать из nginx обычный прокси. Он так не умеет и не предназначен для этого

Comment: А нужен, видимо, squid. Надо разобраться со squid и nginx

Comment: @AlexeyTen предназначен и делает это хорошо. ТС, сделайте `server_name _;`, а если будет конфликт - выставьте другой порт. Nginx вообще может проксировать tcp и udp трафик. Подходит вообще для всего https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: @TotalPusher это будет reverse proxy, а автору явно нужен forwarding proxy. Да, nginx можно настроить как очень простой прокси для http, но это забивание гвоздей отвёрткой

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему? Это одна из ключевых возможностей Nginx, как и реверс-прокси. Есть железная балансировка, есть программная, F5 выкупил Nginx по причине второй.